# Django makemessages javascript (xgettext)

Tags: javascript, django, gettext, django-i18n, xgettext

I want to use django i18n support to translate my javascript files. 
I have the following javascript file:

```
var test_text = gettext('example');

@withStyles(styles)
export default class HomePage {
  static contextTypes = {
    i18n: PropTypes.object
  }

  constructor() {
    this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.handleCitySearch.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid className="HomePage">
        <Row className="HomePage-hero">
          <Col md={8} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
            <Input ref="city" bsSize="large" type="text" />
            <Button bsSize="large" bsStyle="default" onClick={this.handleCitySearch}>{gettext('button text')}</Button>
          </Col>
          <Col md={4}>
            <ul>
              <li>{gettext('SOME TEXT')}</li>
              <li>{gettext('MORE TEXT')}</li>
            </ul>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
      );
  }
}
```

Now I run djangos makemessages command:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l de -d djangojs -v 3 -s
```

I would expect that the created translation file has four entries ('example', 'button text', 'SOME TEXT', and 'MORE TEXT'), because `gettext` appears three times in the js file. 
But the created locale file has only two entry for "example":

```
#: ../HomePage.js:1
msgid "example"
msgstr ""

#: ../HomePage.js:25
msgid "MORE TEXT"
msgstr ""
```

I also get this warning. But have no clue what it means (the file has only 32 lines)

```
HomePage.js:33: warning: RegExp literal terminated too early
```

Does anyone know why django ignores the other entries?
Maybe it's because I use the jsx syntax or because I use es6 classes?

### UPDATE:

I found out that this is not a problem of django but of `xgettext`.
Django calls `xgettext` with the following command:

```
xgettext  --language=JavaScript --keyword=gettext_noop --keyword=gettext_lazy --keyword=ngettext_lazy:1,2 --keyword=pgettext:1c,2 --keyword=npgettext:1c,2,3 --output=- --from-code=UTF-8 --add-comments=Translators  ../HomePage.js
```

So is there any `xgettext` expert who can help me?

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with the latest version of Django (1.10.3). It seemed to work just fine. Can you upgrade your Django version?

The code that worked for me is here: https://github.com/guitarmanvt/stackoverflow-question-32403632

Also, bear in mind that your JavaScript function `gettext` needs to be defined somewhere. When last I looked, there were several JavaScript i18n libraries out there, but not many played well with **xgettext** and **Django**. You may have to roll your own.

Alternatively, take a look at how Sentry does i18n with JSX. https://blog.sentry.io/2016/01/07/react-i18n.html

Happy translating!

Comment: I have the same problem with django 1.10.6 - so the django version update is not enough...

Answer (score 0):

The django version I used previously is 1.5.6, it can extract keywords from .js perfectly. But it throw errors after upgrading to 1.11.15. E.g `warning: unterminated string literal`, `warning: RegExp literal terminated too early`

After much time I dig out the fact: The makemessages.py changed after upgrading. The file is located in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py`, both 1.5.6 and 1.11.15.

In 1.5.6, the flow of makemessage is : 
1. use `prepare_js_for_gettext` form `django.utils.jslex` to pre-processing js files into content that conforms to C language syntax
2. write content to .c file
3. use xgettext extract keywords from .c file and specify language to C

But in 1.11.15, it is: 
1. detect xgettext version, if greater than 1.18.3, use xgettext process js file directly, or process like 1.5.6

The error I got is caused by a bug in xgettext processing js files.

**So I just return `True` line: 77 and all working as before**

```py
    # django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py
    def is_templatized(self):
        if self.domain == 'djangojs':
            return True
            # return self.command.gettext_version < (0, 18, 3)
        elif self.domain == 'django':
            file_ext = os.path.splitext(self.translatable.file)[1]
            return file_ext != '.py'
        return False
```

Maybe you can try this tick or rewrite an script

Answer (score 0):

I'm few years late to the party, but in case anyone finds this helpful...

You are correct, `xgettext --language=JavaScript` doesn't seem to like ES6/JSX.

Using a simple utility such as [the one shown in this article](https://406.ch/writing/gettext-jsx-and-es6-template-literals/) rather than letting `makemessages/xgettext` parse your ES6/JSX files directly might help.

Alternatively there are node packages such as [`gettext-extractor`](https://github.com/lukasgeiter/gettext-extractor) which can be used to write a `.pot` file to `msgmerge` into your `djangojs.po` files... I run a node script using that library (and [`gettext-extractor-vue`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/frontend/gettext-extractor-vue) for my particular use case) to write `frontend/messages.pot`, then this:

```bash
./manage.py makemessages $LANGUAGE_FLAGS $IGNORE_FLAGS
./manage.py makemessages -d djangojs $LANGUAGE_FLAGS $IGNORE_FLAGS
for LANGUAGE in ${LANGUAGES[*]}
do
  PO_PATH=locale/${LANGUAGE}/LC_MESSAGES/djangojs.po
  touch $PO_PATH
  msgmerge -q --previous --update $PO_PATH frontend/messages.pot
done
./manage.py compilemessages
```

And `compilemessages` then generates the appropriate `.mo` files including the node-extracted strings, and Django correctly serves them in `/jsi18n/` catalogue requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the JavaScript code in a file inside the static folder in order to the `djangojs.po` to be generated. Because Django by default look at this destination when dealing with JS files.